# about grep "-i" option in for statment

Tags: python, linux, grep, kali-linux

```
import os
f1 = open("/home/ace/Desktop/MB/shell_search/direct.txt",'r',encoding='UTF-8')
lines = f1.readlines()
lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]

for shell in lines:
 os.system("cat IIS_W3C_Log.log | grep -i \"" + shell + "\" > "+shell+".txt")
```

The -i option does not work...Having a problem with your code?
Uppercase and lowercase letters are distinguished.

If a special character(symbol) is encountered in "shell", the code throws an error. How can I prevent the error from occurring even when the symbol appears?

Comment: You search the filename into the file itself ?

Comment: BTW, `grep` expects a regex to be given as the expression to evaluate. If `direct.txt` doesn't include regular expressions, you might want something like `grep -F` instead.

Comment: @foreaser, a better [mre] would explain an example of the specific sample input that's breaking your code. It's very different if the problem is caused by the string `-bash` vs if it's caused by the string `foo[bar` (for that example, the first is fixed with the `-e` argument to `grep`, and the latter one fixed with the `-F` argument, because they cause two completely different failures... and neither of those failures has anything whatsoever to do with `-i`).

Comment: I learned something new. I'm still a beginner and I have a lot to learn. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.system()` starts a shell. If your `direct.txt` contains `$(rm -rf ~)`, that shell would delete your home directory.

Don't do that, particularly when there's no reason to use a shell at all.

Better code would do the string search in native Python; but if we *wanted* to keep using `grep` for some reason, that might look like:

```
import subprocess

f1 = open("/home/ace/Desktop/MB/shell_search/direct.txt", 'r', encoding='UTF-8')

for line in f1:
    shell = line.strip()
    shell_safe = shell.replace('/', '_').lstrip('.')
    if shell_safe == '':
        print("Skipping unsafe pattern: %q" % shell, file=sys.stderr)
        continue
    subprocess.call(
        ['grep', '-i', '-e', shell],
        stdin=open('IIS_W3C_Log.log', 'r'),
        stdout=open(f'{shell_safe}.txt', 'w')
    )
```

Comment: @foreaser, ...btw, I went back and made some improvements to this answer. It now uses less memory because instead of loading all the lines in the file into memory and processing them before even running the first `grep`, it reads them as it goes; and it's safer, because strings like `../../../../../../etc/passwd` can't be used to overwrite files outside the directory you're working in. (Granted, that example would write to something like `/etc/passwd.txt`, but even overwriting `.txt` files has potential for abuse).